# IndexOutOfBounds Exception ArrayList Loop

Tags: java, arraylist

I am doing a school task on ArrayLists and Wrapper classes. I have to initialize a for loop, which should fill the ArrayList up with the numbers 1 to 99.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++){
   list.add(i);
   System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

The code until the for-loop body is given in the task.

If I run the code, I get an IndexOutOfBounds Exception.

What can I modify to be able to run the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes of list start from 0. So your elements would be from 0 - 99 and not from 1 - 100. access them using `list.get(i-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code as `System.out.println(list.get(i-1));`
because index start from 0.

Answer (score 1):

An array begins always with the index 0. In almost every languages

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++){
   list.add(i);
   System.out.println(list.get(i-1));
}
```

or

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < 99; i++){
   list.add(i+1);
   System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```